how to strip certain patterns in column headers and rename them all in one go
I have given my students two assessments and each has about 40 items long.  Each assessment was given twice, once at pre-assessment and once again at post-assessment.  The vocabulary column headers has one word that describes the content of each assessment item whereas the background knowledge (identified as bk in my dataset) has up to 4 words that describe the item.  To demonstrate what I mean, the following is a sample dataset.  What's tricky about this dataset is that the item order for the same question changes from pre- to post assessment.  So for example, the "captivity" question was the first question at pre-assessment but was the 17th question at post. Same thing with bk. Values of 0s and 1s tell me whether students that got question correct (1s) for that item or not (0s).
df <- data.frame(vocab_pre_1_captivity_key=c(0, 1),
             vocab_post_17_captivity_key=c(1,0),
             bk_pre_1_food_chains_key=c(1,0),
             bk_post_16_food_chains_key=c(0,1),
             bk_pre_6_humans_harmed_orcas_key=c(0,1),
             bk_post_15_humans_harmed_orcas_key=c(1,0))

What I would ultimately like to accomplish is to report proportion correct for each item in a table side by side.  However, to do that, I need the column headers to be renamed as follows:
captivity_pre
captivity_post
food_chains_pre
food_chains_post
humans_harmed_orcas_pre
humans_harmed_orcas_post
I've been scratching my head and one way that I know how to do this is to rename each individual column using dplyr::rename.  However, this would be so tedious.  I'm hoping if someone could show me a much more elegant solution to this problem.  This is something that I will be doing again in future studies and it would be great to learn a more sustainable solution to this problem.  Thank you for your time and any assistance you can provide.

You can use str_remove and other functions from the {stringr} package to modify column names using the rename_with function, which allows you to rename all your columns at once. The following code gets you close:
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df2 <- df |> 
  tibble() |> 
  rename_with(~str_remove(.x, "bk_")) |> 
  rename_with(~str_remove(.x, "vocab_")) |> 
  rename_with(~str_remove(.x, "\\d+_")) |> # this is regex for "any number followed by _"
  rename_with(~str_remove(.x, "_key"))

> names(df2)
[1] "pre_captivity"            "post_captivity"           "pre_food_chains"         
[4] "post_food_chains"         "pre_humans_harmed_orcas"  "post_humans_harmed_orcas"

Then, you can further use rename_with to paste "pre" and "post" at the end of names, and then removing both strings from the beginning of the column names, so that we end up with your desired result:
df3 <- df2 |> 
  # add "pre" and "post" to the end of the column names
  rename_with(~paste0(.x, "_pre"), contains("pre")) |> 
  rename_with(~paste0(.x, "_post"), contains("post")) |> 
  # remove "pre" and "post" from the beginning of column names
  rename_with(~str_remove(.x, "pre_")) |> 
  rename_with(~str_remove(.x, "post_"))

> names(df3)
[1] "captivity_pre"            "captivity_post"           "food_chains_pre"         
[4] "food_chains_post"         "humans_harmed_orcas_pre"  "humans_harmed_orcas_post"

This method is more readable, but you can also use the "or" operator (|) inside the str_remove functions to make this code shorter, for example, using ~str_remove(.x, "pre_|post_") to delete both strings at the same time instead of using str_remove twice.

This solution worked very well and it's very intuitive to me.  Thank you so much for your time and expertise!

I'm glad it helped you, @Anita! Please mark the question as solved ☺️

Just did.  Thanks again!

You can use a lookup table combined with the !!! in rename like this
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(dplyr))
library(stringr)

df <- data.frame(vocab_pre_1_captivity_key=c(0, 1),
             vocab_post_17_captivity_key=c(1,0),
             bk_pre_1_food_chains_key=c(1,0),
             bk_post_16_food_chains_key=c(0,1),
             bk_pre_6_humans_harmed_orcas_key=c(0,1),
             bk_post_15_humans_harmed_orcas_key=c(1,0))


rename_lookup = data.frame(old = colnames(df))  |>
  mutate(pre_post = str_extract(old, "pre|post"),
         activity = str_extract(old, 'captivity|food_chains|humans_harmed_orcas'),
        new = paste0(activity,'_', pre_post)) |>
  select(new, old) |>
  tibble::deframe()

df |>
  rename(!!!rename_lookup)
#>   captivity_pre captivity_post food_chains_pre food_chains_post
#> 1             0              1               1                0
#> 2             1              0               0                1
#>   humans_harmed_orcas_pre humans_harmed_orcas_post
#> 1                       0                        1
#> 2                       1                        0

Created on 2024-07-22 with reprex v2.1.1

Thank you for your help!  This approach worked but it seems to require that I have to provide a complete look-up table with all the column names and I was trying to avoid doing that :).

Not sure if this is what you're asking but you can rename the columns with
colnames(df) <- lapply(colnames(df), \(x){ 
  res <- strsplit(x, "_")[[1]]
  loc <- grep("\\d+", res)
  paste(c(res[loc + 1:((length(res) - loc) - 1)], res[2]), collapse="_")})

df
  captivity_pre captivity_post food_chains_pre food_chains_post
1             0              1               1                0
2             1              0               0                1
  humans_harmed_orcas_pre humans_harmed_orcas_post
1                       0                        1
2                       1                        0

It's looking for the digit in the strsplit string (loc). From there it takes the strings following loc until the second to last string. Finally add the string before loc, namely "pre" or "post".

This worked, although I will need to spend sometime figuring out the code in spite of your explanation :). Thank you for your expertise and time!
